# don't stop bundle install for an error on particular gem

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler

Is it possible to continue `bundle install` on error.

Problem: There is a list of gems out of which few will give error but rest are just fine, but bundle install stops at error and wouldn't continue.

**Errors like this:**

```
Gem::InstallError: ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.18'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```